# Trying to override link style inside an html div but it isn't working

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to css coding. I've been searching the net for help but I'm not finding any solutions that help. The furthest I've come to setting up my code is as posted below.

The CSS code I entered into my CSS window on an individual page is:

```css
div.box_round_background {
          padding: 5px;
}

div.box_round {
          -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1+ */
          -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4 */
          border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
          background-color: #86ae30;
}



div.box_round h1 {
          color: #ffffff;
          padding: 20px;
}


a.box_round h1:link { color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
a.box_round h1:visited { color: #e1efc3; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
a.box_round h1:hover { color: #5c7821; text-decoration:underline; font-weight:normal; }
a.box_round h1:active { color: #a4ce4b; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
```

And the code I've inserted into my html source is:

```html
<div class="box_round_background">
   <div class="box_round">
 <a href="/web-design-services"><h1>Web Design Services</h1></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm not getting the result I need with the link colors. It's not having much effect on the link colors at all.

Can anyone please help me work out what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try changing the css selectors from

```
    a.box_round h1:link
    a.box_round h1:visited
    a.box_round h1:hover
    a.box_round h1:active
```

to

```
    .box_round a:link h1
    .box_round a:visited h1
    .box_round a:hover h1
    .box_round a:active h1
```

Comment: I tried that but then it changes the links on the entire page. I only need a specific section to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Css is working from higher to closer so when you say `div.box_round h1` you mean the `h1` in the `.box_roud` however in the code provided there is no `h1` only `a` tag.

So you just have to change h1 by a :

```css
div.box_round_background {
          padding: 5px;
}

div.box_round {
          -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1+ */
          -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4 */
          border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
          background-color: #86ae30;
}



div.box_round a {
          color: #ffffff;
          padding: 20px;
}


.box_round a:link { color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
.box_round a:visited { color: #e1efc3; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
.box_round a:hover { color: #5c7821; text-decoration:underline; font-weight:normal; }
.box_round a:active { color: #a4ce4b; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
```

```html
<div class="box_round_background">
   <div class="box_round">
 <a href="/web-design-services"><h1>Web Design Services</h1></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your method and it removed all of the text coding. There is an h1 in the html code. 

<a href="/web-design-services"><h1>Web Design Services</h1></a>